# Icon size of OriginLab virtualised on Mavericks

Tags: macos, windows-8, icons, charts, parallels

I hope that someone can help me because I'm freaking out!

I just installed [Origin 9.1](http://www.originlab.com) on a Mac (15 retina late 2013) using parallels 10 on Windows 8.1

Everything is fine, but, due to the high resolution of the macbook screen the icons are really just too small. Is there a way to increase the icon size inside Origin?

I'm really short sighted and working is really painful under this conditions!

I hope someone can be so kind to help me with this.

Thanks in advance for your patience!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just found it

1) Choose "View: Toolbars" menu, and select "Options" tab in the Customize dialog.

2) Turn ON the check box of "Use Large Icons".